# making a function of turning lowercase string into uppercase string in c

Tags: c, string, function

I'm still a beginner at making function and C programming.
I'm trying to make a function for turning it into uppercase, but it seems I messed it up at the pointer(?)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mytoupper(char *s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
            s[i] = s[i] - 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[32];
    printf("Insert string:");
    printf("%s", s);
    printf("%s", mytoupper(s[32]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to `scanf` instead of `printf("%s", s);`

Comment: Typo in the code: `printf("%s", s);` to `scanf("%s", s);` regardless of other deficiencies.

Comment: `mytoupper(s[32])` -> `mytoupper(s)`

Comment: `void mytoupper(char * s[])` needs to be either `void mytoupper(char *s)` or `void mytoupper(char s[])`.

Comment: ... and it should not return anything. Breaking the `printf("%s", mytoupper(s[32]));` line second time.

Comment: `scanf("%s", s)` is akin to `gets(s)` - neither should ever be used.  `scanf("%31s", s)` with its width prevents buffer overrun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the definition for `mytoupper` is incorrect: it should take a `char *s` argument instead of `char *s[]`, and return `char *`.
- Changing the character from lower to upper case should not use a hard coded value of `32` that only works for ASCII, use a more generic approach with `s[i] = s[i] - 'a' + 'A';`
- To read the string, use `scanf("%31s", s);` instead of `printf("%s", s);` and it is highly recommended to test the return value of `scanf()`
- The argument in `printf("%s", mytoupper(s[32]));` is incorrect: you should just write `printf("%s", mytoupper(s));`

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *mytoupper(char *s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
            s[i] = s[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
        i++;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[32];
    printf("Insert string:");
    if (scanf("%31s", s) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", mytoupper(s));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i space it, it only uppercase the first word. To prevent it, should i use fgets?

Comment: `scanf` with `%s` reads just one word. If you wish to process a whole line, use `fgets` with a larger buffer. If you wish to process the whole standard input stream contents, use a while loop, testing the return value of `fgets()`: `while (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) { fputs(mytoupper(s), stdout); }`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few spots that will not work as expected in your code.

1. You are not properly getting user input, instead you are trying to print an 'empty' string.

   ```
   printf("%s",s);
   ```

   You could change this to:

   ```
   scanf("%31s",s);
   ```
2. You are accepting an array of char pointers in your function `mytoupper`, but this is not needed. You can instead simply pass it an array of chars.

   ```
   void mytoupper(char s[])
   ```
3. You are attempting to use a return value of a `void` function. You can either call the function then print the string, or have the function return the string.

   If you want to change the string then print it seperately you will need to change `mytoupper` to no longer return anything and keep it as a `void` return type.

   ```
   mytoupper(s);
   printf("%s", s);
   ```

   Or change the function to:

   ```
   char* mytoupper(char s[]) {
   ```

   Then print the string:

   ```
   printf("%s", mytoupper(s));
   ```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s);` passes the wrong type.  Drop the `&` and recommend to employ a width limit. `scanf("%31s",s);` - or even better, use `fgets()`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s);` is wrong. It might "work" if `s` is defined locally, but if `s` is a function argument, there is a big difference between `s` and `&s`.

Comment: `char *s[]` is not a pointer to an array, it's an array of pointers.